# Spirit X3: attribute of alternative parser, not `char`, but `variant<char, char>`

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

According to spirit x3 attribute collapsing rule, the attribute of an anternative parser with 2 
alternation having same attribute, should collapse, i.e. `a: A, b: A --> (a | b): A`, but the code below shows its not, is it a bug or my fault?

Here is the spirit x3 documentation of compound attribute rules https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/spirit_x3/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html

I've got a code snippet to reproduce this question

Here is the code `https://wandbox.org/permlink/7MvN03yiX7ir3esE`

And the original code in case the link expired

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

using x3::_val;
using x3::_attr;
using x3::_where;
using fusion::at_c;

auto const string_def = x3::lexeme["\"" >> *(x3::symbols<char>({ {"\\\"", '"'} }) | (x3::print - '\"')) > "\""][([](auto& ctx) {
    std::cout << typeid(_attr(ctx)).name();
    //should _attr(ctx) be a vector<char>, according to attribute collapsing rule?
})];

int main() {
    std::string input = R"__("hello\"world")__";
    x3::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), string_def);
}
```

Bascally, the code parse a string literal, which contains a number of chars (`*`), which is either a character except `'"'` (`x3::print-'"')`, or a escape sequence `"\\\""` representing the character `'"'` (`x3::symbol<char>...`), both of them has a attribute of `char`, and `char | char` should be `char`, not `variant<char, char>`.

the `cout` part of the code shows result like `St6vectorIN5boost7variantINS0_6detail7variant13over_sequenceINS0_3mpl6l_itemIN4mpl_5long_ILl2EEEcNS6_INS8_ILl1EEEcNS5_5l_endEEEEEEEJEEESaISF_EE`, after demangling, it is `vector<variant<over_sequence<...>>>` and `variant<over_sequence<>` is basically a workaround of `variant<T...>` in pre-C++11 times.

So what's wrong with the code, should it be `vector<char>`, not `vector<variant>`? And BTW, can I customize attribute collapsing rule myself?

Comment: Just a side note: I'd call `std::variant` a workaround, because it's much less powerful than `boost::variant` :)

Comment: As for you question, I guess you do not observe collapsing because semantic action suppresses attribute propagation. Instead of the semantic action, try to parse all this into `std::string`.

Comment: @IgorR. thanks for the comment, I now know why, but I do need parsing this into a unique_ptr<string> for some consistency in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @IgorR. mentioned in comment, semantic action suppresses attribute propagation, I ignored that point. So problem solved, I might need just parse this into std::string.

For some reason I need parsing this into a unique_ptr object, so I need separate the parser into a `rule<StringContent, std::string>` and a `rule<StringLiteral, std::unique_ptr<ast::StringLiteral>, true>`, problem solved